# How to remove http:// using jQuery (Wordpress)?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, http

I need to remove http:// which is in an existing code.

I tried the following jQuery, but both codes don't remove http://.
Would you please let me know how to remove it?

jQuery I tried:

```
jQuery(".elementor-button-wrapper").find("http://").each(function(){
    var linkText = $(this).text();
    $(this).remove();
});

jQuery('.elementor-button-wrapper a [href="http://]').each(function() { this.setAttribute('href', ''); });
```

Existing code:

```
<div class="elementor-button-wrapper">
<a href="http://https://www.myweb.com/hereis" class="elementor-button-link elementor-button elementor-size-sm" role="button">
    <span class="elementor-button-text">Read More</span>
</a>
</div>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following script should get the current value of the href attribute of the link element inside the elementor-button-wrapper div, remove the http:// string or replace it with blank, then apply the newlink back to the link's href attribute.

```js
jQuery(".elementor-button-wrapper").each(function(){
        var link = jQuery(this).find("a");
        var newlink = link.attr("href").replace('http://', '');
        link.attr("href", newlink);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="elementor-button-wrapper">
<a href="http://https://www.myweb.com/hereis" class="elementor-button-link elementor-button elementor-size-sm" role="button">
    <span class="elementor-button-text">Read More</span>
</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi iismaell: Wow, it works perfectly. Thank you a lot for your help : )

Comment: No problem. I think nadz solution is a better approach, so you should use it instead.

Comment: Hi iismaell: oh, I get it, let me try it, thank you for your advice : )

Answer (score 1):

You could try this.

```js
function FormatLink(link, keyword) {
  var index = link.indexOf(keyword);
  if (index === -1) {
    return link;
  }
  return link.slice(0, index) + link.slice(index + keyword.length);
}

$("a").each(function() {
  if ($(this).attr("href").indexOf("http://") != -1) {
    var link = FormatLink($(this).attr("href"), 'http://');
    $(this).attr("href", link);
    console.log(link);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="elementor-button-wrapper">

  <a href="http://https://www.myweb.com/hereis" class="elementor-button-link elementor-button elementor-size-sm" role="button">
    <span class="elementor-button-text">Read More</span>
  </a>
  
  <a href="http://https://www.myweb.com/hereis" class="elementor-button-link elementor-button elementor-size-sm" role="button">
    <span class="elementor-button-text">Read More</span>
  </a>
  
  <a href="https://www.myweb.com/hereis" class="elementor-button-link elementor-button elementor-size-sm" role="button">
    <span class="elementor-button-text">Read More</span>
  </a>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Hi nadz: Thank you for your help : )

Comment: hi hi , I tried your code but it displays error on the first line => syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE). So I changed it to => link. keyword, but it still shows error. Would you please tell me how to deal with this? (I'm sorry, I'm a newbie, so very clumsy...)